# Linux mem kernel option caps at 12GB?

Tags: linux, debian

When I set the `mem=16G` kernel option on a 14GB RAM machine, `free -m` reports 12GB of free memory. If I try `mem=16G` on a 7GB RAM machine, it doesn't change at all.

Is this a bug, or is there a way around it?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry, edited it.

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system (w/ PAE)? I can't see that happening on a 64-bit one.

Comment: It's still not clear what you think is a bug. What behavior do you expect exactly?

Comment: When I set mem=16G I expected it to report 16G of memory in both cases, but it worked in neither cases which is confusing.

Comment: What's your outer problem exactly? Are you trying to force the kernel to pretend it has memory where devices are mapped so that when it tries to access this memory, it will be sending garbage commands to hardware devices?!

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your BIOS is set up to allow your RAM to be shared with your video card, which, I understand, reduces the memory reported under Linux, presumably because its no longer available to the OS.  That says 2 gigs does seem to be quite a bit.